# Connect two objects using fabric js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I currently have a canvas application where I can add objects(shapes). Here is my [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vxqL4yg9/). You basically click on new simulation which will initialize the canvas, then you can add a circle or rectangle.

I am trying to add a feature called "Add child" where you can click on some object (shape) then click add child and add another object(shape) and they are both linked with a line. Something similar to this [DEMO](http://fabricjs.com/stickman/).

I figured the pesudo code for this feature would go something like  as following:

```
function addChild(){

    get getActiveObject
    draw a line/arrow connect it with getActiveObject
    draw object connected with line
    should be able to move it / strecth it around


}
```

I was wondering if this is possible and how to start. Please advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to listen for the `object:selected` event to add the connecting line and the `object:moving` event to update the line coordinates.

```
// function for drawing a line
function makeLine(coords) {
    return new fabric.Line(coords, {
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        selectable: false
    });
}

var canvas; 
window.newAnimation = function(){
   canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

   var selectedElement = null;
   canvas.on('object:selected', function(options) {
       // we are doing t oadd a connection
       if (canvas.connect) {
           canvas.connect = false;
           var from = selectedElement.getCenterPoint();
           var to = options.target.getCenterPoint();
           var line = makeLine([from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y]);
           canvas.add(line);

           // these take care of moving the line ends when the object moves
           selectedElement.moveLine = function() {
               var from = selectedElement.getCenterPoint();
               line.set({ 'x1': from.x, 'y1': from.y });
           };
           options.target.moveLine = function() {
               var to = options.target.getCenterPoint();
               line.set({ 'x2': to.x, 'y2': to.y });
           };
       }
       selectedElement = options.target;
   });

   canvas.on('object:moving', function(e) {
        e.target.moveLine();
        canvas.renderAll();
  });
}

window.addChild = function() {
   canvas.connect = true;
}
```

The window.addChild keeps track of the whether Add Child was clicked (and should be added to the onclick for the button) so that the next `object:selected` can draw the line (otherwise it simply keeps track of the currently selected element)

```
<button onClick="addChild()">Add Child</button>
```

Note that for a full solution you need to be able to cancel out of an Add Child and you probably want to handle object resizing (currently the line updates when you move the object but does not when you resize the object)

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/ctcdaxop/

Comment: This is wonderful, in order to cancel add child I guess should I simply delete the active object ? for example i select on a child object it is considered active object, should i delete that simply?

Comment: Just set `canvas.connect` to false.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6zqbq7rp/ This is what i did but for some reason i can't delete the connecting line. I even tried to set canvas.connect to false. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Ah OK, you need to store a reference to the line object, add a method to delete it and call it when the object is deleted. You'll also need to handle missing lines in the move handler. Give it a spin or i can fiddle it  a few hours later.

Comment: sure no problem thanks i will try best to do it also when i tried separating code that connects two objects to a new function there were some issues. The reason being is the newAnimation function I was strictly trying to keep it to create a new canvas. So if you do get a chance letter also let me know if that is possible. Thanks again for wonderful contribution.

Comment: @user1010101 - I've added another answer (since it is different from this one if you want to support deletions). I'm afraid we can't move all the code out of newAnimation since we need to attach the handlers and for this you need the initialized canvas object (which is available only in the new animation handler). By the way clicking new animation just initializes a new canvas - you should be clearing up the old canvas element and it's objects.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a new version of what you are looking for including support for multiple connections and deletion

**Add Child Functionality**

```
function addChildLine(options) {
    canvas.off('object:selected', addChildLine);

    // add the line
    var fromObject = canvas.addChild.start;
    var toObject = options.target;
    var from = fromObject.getCenterPoint();
    var to = toObject.getCenterPoint();
    var line = new fabric.Line([from.x, from.y, to.x, to.y], {
        fill: 'red',
        stroke: 'red',
        strokeWidth: 5,
        selectable: false
    });
    canvas.add(line);
    // so that the line is behind the connected shapes
    line.sendToBack();

    // add a reference to the line to each object
    fromObject.addChild = {
        // this retains the existing arrays (if there were any)
        from: (fromObject.addChild && fromObject.addChild.from) || [],
        to: (fromObject.addChild && fromObject.addChild.to)
    }
    fromObject.addChild.from.push(line);
    toObject.addChild = {
        from: (toObject.addChild && toObject.addChild.from),
        to: (toObject.addChild && toObject.addChild.to) || []
    }
    toObject.addChild.to.push(line);

    // to remove line references when the line gets removed
    line.addChildRemove = function () {
        fromObject.addChild.from.forEach(function(e, i, arr) {
            if (e === line)
                arr.splice(i, 1);
        });
        toObject.addChild.to.forEach(function (e, i, arr) {
            if (e === line)
                arr.splice(i, 1);
        });
    }

    // undefined instead of delete since we are anyway going to do this many times
    canvas.addChild = undefined;
}

function addChildMoveLine(event) {
    canvas.on(event, function (options) {
        var object = options.target;
        var objectCenter = object.getCenterPoint();
        // udpate lines (if any)
        if (object.addChild) {
            if (object.addChild.from)
                object.addChild.from.forEach(function (line) {
                    line.set({ 'x1': objectCenter.x, 'y1': objectCenter.y });
                })
            if (object.addChild.to)
                object.addChild.to.forEach(function (line) {
                    line.set({ 'x2': objectCenter.x, 'y2': objectCenter.y });
                })
        }

        canvas.renderAll();
    });
}

window.addChild = function () {
    canvas.addChild = {
        start: canvas.getActiveObject()
    }

    // for when addChild is clicked twice
    canvas.off('object:selected', addChildLine);
    canvas.on('object:selected', addChildLine);
}
```

Since we don't have a canvas reference unless Add Animation is clicked the handler has to be attached in the Add Animation handler

```
window.newAnimation = function () {
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

    // we need this here because this is when the canvas gets initialized
    ['object:moving', 'object:scaling'].forEach(addChildMoveLine)
}
```

---

**Deleting Lines when Deleting Objects**

```
window.deleteObject = function () {
    var object = canvas.getActiveObject();

    // remove lines (if any)
    if (object.addChild) {
        if (object.addChild.from)
            // step backwards since we are deleting
            for (var i = object.addChild.from.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var line = object.addChild.from[i];
                line.addChildRemove();
                line.remove();
            }
        if (object.addChild.to)
            for (var i = object.addChild.to.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var line = object.addChild.to[i];
                line.addChildRemove();
                line.remove();
            }
    }

    // from original code
    object.remove();
}
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xvcyzh9p/

Comment: shall i post this as a seprate question so you can answer it there? I did upvote i feel it should get more reward.

Comment: No problem, just leave it as is - the upvote is good enough. Cheers!

Comment: Hey i just posted a new question, maybe you can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670825/add-animation-between-two-objects-in-fabric-js

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if you had any chance to look at my question :). I was going through Fabric JS animation tutorial @ http://fabricjs.com/animation-easing/