# Add animation between two objects in Fabric js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a very basic application that let's you create shapes and connect them with a line. To do that you would do the following.

```
Example

1. Click new animation
2. add rectangle
3. add child
4. add circle
```

You can move the shapes around , drag, and resize. I was wondering if it is possible to add a animation between two objects. So for example a small round circle ball would animate on the line between two objects. I have checked out demos on animation page in fabric js but not sure if it is possible to do from object b.

Here is the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xvcyzh9p/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if you can use the built in animation function in fabric because as you say these objects might be moving around themselves. But you can make something like this quite easily manually using a bit of Math:

[image]

You could do this by treating it like a wave oscillating between 0 and 1. The correct formula for this function is:

[image]

- When the "angle" is 0, or a multiple of 2π the amplitude is 0, so the ball is at object1's center
- When the "angle" is a multiple of π, the amplitude is 1 and the ball is at object2's center
- When the amplitude is 0.5, the ball is in between the two objects

You can just increase the angle based on the time, on whatever period, or duration you want.

```
var animateBallBetweenObjects = function (obj1, obj2) {

    // Add the "ball"

    var circle = new fabric.Circle({
        radius: 10,
        fill: 'blue',
        left: obj1.getCenterPoint().x,
        top: obj1.getCenterPoint().y,
        originX: 'center',
        originY: 'middle',
        selectable: false
    });

    canvas.add(circle);

    var period = 1000;
    var amplitude = 0;
    var angle = 0;
    var prevTime = Date.now();

    var loop = function () {

        // Calculate the new amplitude

        var now = Date.now();
        var elapsed = now - prevTime;
        prevTime = now;
        angle += Math.PI * (elapsed / (period * 0.5));
        amplitude = 0.5 * (Math.sin(angle - (0.5 * Math.PI)) + 1);

        // Set the new position

        var obj1Center = obj1.getCenterPoint();
        var obj2Center = obj2.getCenterPoint();

        circle.setLeft(obj1Center.x + (amplitude * (obj2Center.x - obj1Center.x)));
        circle.setTop(obj1Center.y + (amplitude * (obj2Center.y - obj1Center.y)));
        canvas.renderAll();

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }

    // Animate as fast as possible

    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1b7phzuy/2/) with it here.

Comment: So basically say after I have created parent shape and child shape. I was wondering if it is possible to create an animation function which we would tell us to select the parent and child. So for example you can have many parent child on the canvas and when you click on create animation you can specify which parent child you want to add animation too.

Comment: What you posted is very close to what i was looking for. I am going to play around with it just a little bit and make sure i

Comment: @user1010101 I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if you can have more than one of these animations at a time? The answer is yes, you can have as many as you want: https://mattharrison.s3.amazonaws.com/stackoverflow/animation.gif

Comment: Hi sorry, what I meant is is it possible that we add a new function called animation that takes parent id and child as arguments and creates animation between them. So from user point of view we would basically create a rectangle then add another shape say circle as its child. Then we would click on a button called add animation and then we would select on the two objects we want to animate. After that the animation would take place. Please let me know if this is not clear also.

Comment: Yes that's possible. It is however a different question altogether than this.

Comment: sure, so do you suggest I ask it seprately? I can accept this

Comment: Yes, you should attempt it yourself and then open a new question showing what you've tried and where you've ran into trouble with it.